# Route with ID from div

Tags: laravel, variables, routes, href

How do you correctly route in Laravel when on click and pass the ID along?
I have a  using vue that prints out every element of an array.
Like this:

```
<div v-for="album in albums" :key="album.id" class="border-2 w-3/4 h-48 bg-sky-500  ">
    <a href="/album/">{{ album.title  }}</a>
  </div>
```

As you can see im trying to route using `href`. How can i pass the album.id alongside that? So the route would be for an example `localhost:8000/album/5`

Thanks for any help, i do appreciate it.

Comment: Check out the [Tighten `Ziggy`](https://github.com/tighten/ziggy) package.

Answer (score 1):

@Gev99

Thanks for the reply mate.

I fixed it by doing this:

```
<div v-for="album in albums" :key="album.id" class="border-2 w-3/4 h-48 bg-sky-500  ">
    <a v-bind:href="'/album/'+ album.id"> {{ album.title }} </a>
  </div>
```

I will try out yours aswell! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
//web.php
Route::get('albume/{id}',[MyController::class,'MyMethod'])->name('albume');
```

//in vue file

```
 <div v-for="(album,idx) in albums" :key="idx" class="border-2 w-3/4 h-48 bg-sky-500  ">
    <a :href="route('album',album.id)">{{ album.title  }}</a>
  </div>
```

This is the best way